# .url file displays text instead of going to the website

Tags: file, url

I have .url files on a server and when I click on them, I see the content of the file instead of having the browser going to the url. As an example, try clicking on this:

```
http://69.160.61.109/document/116_1.url
```

The code in the url:
    [DEFAULT]
    BASEURL=http://www.agriculturemorethanever.ca/
    [DOC_gform_ajax_frame_3]
    BASEURL=about:blank
    ORIGURL=about:blank
    [InternetShortcut]
    URL=http://www.agriculturemorethanever.ca/
    IDList=
    IconFile=http://www.agriculturemorethanever.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/favicon1.ico
    IconIndex=1
    [{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
    Prop3=19,2

I tried with IE9 and FF 15. If I download the file on my desktop, it opens properly.

Thanks for your help.

Luc

Comment: you would probbably like that this link issue a file download dialog in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

".url" files are a Windows specific file format and have no meaning when served from the Internet.

If you want to send a visitor to another website you have several options.

### URL Rewrite

If you are running apache with mod_rewrite you can add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule path-to-file http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Other web servers have similar options.

### HTTP Header

You can send an HTTP Location header and 301 response code. The example below uses PHP, but any server programming language has similar functionality.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://example.com/", true, 301);
exit;
?>
```

### Meta Refresh (not recommended for usability reasons)

This will break the back button on some browsers, so use carefully.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Up until recently, .url used to work but I move to another server and it's no longer working. Could there be a setup to do on the server so that it would work? The reason why I like .url so much is that I run an advertising contest and people submit their entries online uploading files of their material. Creating a .url files was fairly easy for marketers to do and they could upload it like any other files. Looks like my best option is to create a converter in php that will read the .url and redirect the person to the right site.

Comment: They may work on some systems if the correct content type is sent, but there would be no guarantee. Can you ask for a URL instead? Or your converted idea could also work.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the servers these days are hosted in linux. And servers do not fetch the request and they do not direct/redirect unless webbrowsers are told to do so. In your case the .url file is merely nothing than a file containing few texts. This same file works in windows after downloading because .url file are the shortcuts or hyperlink file which is recognized by windows. Thus windows automatically takes you to the website. Please read more about .url file in the link http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article

If you are trying to have similar kind of behaviour such that clicking on .url file on server takes your to the corresponding web-url then you'll have to implement somekind of javascript tricks or use php server side scripts such that clicking on url file trigger request the browsesr to redirect browser to the link contained in the .url file.

Hope this answer your question.